# ajax setTimeout not working on json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**AJAX function**

```
var stopTime = 0;
 var checkRequApprove =  function ()
    {
      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkApproveReq',
      success:function(output){
        jsn=JSON.parse(output);
        if(output==false){
         stopTime = setTimeout(checkRequApprove, 3000); 
            }
        else {
              bootbox.dialog({
              message: "Battle",
              title: "Request Accepted",
              buttons:
               {
                  success: {
                  label: "Approve",
                  className: "btn-success",
                  callback: function() {
                       $.ajax({    
                        "type" : "POST",
                        "url" : "finalBattleApprove",
                        "data" : {'username' : jsn.user_name},
                       success: function(data){
                           $('#example').html(data);
                           $('#loadingmessage').show();
                        }
                     });
                  }
                  },
            }
    }
  });
}
  stopTime = setTimeout(checkRequApprove,3000);
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkApproveReq(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $requApprove = '1';
    $check = $this->lawmodel->checkRequApprove($id,$requApprove);
    foreach($check as $row){
        if($row->requApprove == '1')
        {
        $reqID = $this->lawmodel->getID($row->requestedID);
        foreach($reqID as $row){
        echo json_encode(
        array(
             'user_name' =>$row->username,
            )
        );
    }
    }
    else
    echo false;
    }
}
```

I have this code wherein there is a realtime check to the database and if the condition has meet..custom dialog will pop up.
Im having this problem on my `checkRequApprove` function..The `bootbox.dialog` will not showup if the condition is meet in the controller...
i believe that my problem is because in the controller which `echo json_encode`. I cant find any solution .im still a newbie in ajax..

**EDITED**
the custom dialog will only show after i refresh the page.

Comment: Does the success callback get triggered?

Comment: cant tell because the bootbox.dialog will not showup..when i tried to change the `json_encode` in controller into `echo $id` the dialog box will show..but i cant continue coz in my callback: will get a value from `json_encode`.

Comment: You can not tell? A simple console.log() or break point tells you that. Add a error handler to the Ajax call.

Comment: sorry..i edited my question a little..coz i find it strange. the custom dialog will only show after i refresh the page..

Comment: So it runs once and you expect it to run again? If you want the function to run again, you need to call a new timeout, you are not running an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output` is a string - the comparison `output == false` will always yield false, because a non-empty string is always true (not considering the edgecase "0" in which case "0" == false yields true).

Instead of

```
if(output==false){
   ...
}
```

it should be:

```
if (!jsn){ // or jsn == false if you like that better
   ...
}
```

Also you should consider not returning a simple value in your controller, but always a proper json-object like:

```
else{    // consider always using brackets, for more robustness
    echo
         array(
             'error' => true
            );
}
```

Now, in your js you just check for

```
if (jsn.error){
   ...
}
```

In any case, you should include an error callback for your json to handle possible errors with the json request.